# Ul li:hover HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got this problem.

My nav bar is 2.5rem.
And i've made an ul li:hover font size increase.

But if I hover over my list element, the whole nav bar size increases to the size of my `li` too.

How can I block this?

```css
.navsecond  {
    background-color: rgb(88, 87, 80);
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 2.5rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: auto;
    float: left;
}

ul li:hover {
    color:rgb(233, 206, 119);
    font-size: larger;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

li {
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: white;
    
}
```

```html
<div>
 <nav class="navsecond">
    <ul>
      <li><b>Hallo</b></li>   
      <li><b>Hallo</b></li>
      <li><b>Hallo</b></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the font-size, `scale` the element....which also means you can add a transition.

```css
.navsecond  {
    background-color: rgb(88, 87, 80);
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 2.5rem;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: auto;
    float: left;
}

ul li:hover {
    color:rgb(233, 206, 119);
    /* this */
    transform: scale(1.25);
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    transition: transform .33s ease;
}

li {
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: white;
    
}
```

```html
<div>
 <nav class="navsecond">
    <ul>
      <li><b>Hallo</b></li>   
      <li><b>Hallo</b></li>
      <li><b>Hallo</b></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: This was it. Thx mate. Learned i should use transform instead.

Answer (score 1):

Giving static height to nav would solve your problem

```css
.navsecond  {
    background-color: rgb(88, 87, 80);
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 2.5rem;
    height: 70px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: auto;
    float: left;
}

ul li:hover {
    color:rgb(233, 206, 119);
    font-size: larger;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

li {
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: white;
    
}
```

```html
<div>
 <nav class="navsecond">
    <ul>
      <li><b>Hallo</b></li>   
      <li><b>Hallo</b></li>
      <li><b>Hallo</b></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```